# using "was" twice in this sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In this sentence should it be public "was" given or does the first "was" cover it?

> *A notice was published in the newspaper, and the public given 30 days to comment.*

Comment: Your sentence is perfectly fine as written.

Comment: The comma before "and" bothers me.

Answer (score 3):

The first one covers it. This is *[ellipsis](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ellipsis)*, and perfectly acceptable.